# is there a tmux pre-command for when i run tmux kill session

Tags: tmux

Suppose i have a tmux session with a process running like a docker container / wsgi server etc..

Is there a way to define a "process kill command" that will run before the tmux session is killed?
I don't want any leftovers when the session has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tmux hooks](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#HOOKS) for this. Set the hook in your `tmux.conf` like this:

```
set-hook -g -n 'session-closed' 'run "<your command>"'
```

I am not sure you need it though. When `tmux kill-session` is run, all processes inside tmux will receive SIGHUP, so they should exit gracefully on their own.

Answer (score 0):

If your process can be killed with `Ctrl+c`, a tmux plugin called [tmux-safekill](https://github.com/jlipps/tmux-safekill) may do the trick.